# how countdownlatch is useful in web application? Can we get one real time scenario?

Tags: java

how does CountDownlatch is useful in web application? Can some one explain one real time scenario?

```
public class CountDownLatchTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CountDownLatch cdlatch=new CountDownLatch(5);
    new Event(cdlatch);

    try {
        cdlatch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("event executed done!");

}

}

public class Event implements Runnable{

CountDownLatch cdlatch;

public Event(CountDownLatch cdlatch) {
    new Thread(this).start();
    this.cdlatch=cdlatch;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        System.out.println("event "+i);
        cdlatch.countDown();
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> > Can some one explain one real time scenario?

Consider your web application should not serve any request until say:

- You cache some data from DB or any outside world entity.
- All your worker threads are up and ready to serve request.

Once that is done, then only you could start processing the request. In this case if you start processing say before caching the data then it might happen you will process request with null data.

Comment: In web application i have one page ,which as balance information and transactions. If i want to load page only when balance information event is completed then i work with transactions and then show the page does it work over here? please explain?